# What is the distinct difference between "Std" and "Standard" markings on Jeppesen charts?

Tags: aeronautical-charts, jeppesen, symbology

What is the difference between "Std" and "Standard" markings on Jeppesen charts? I read the descriptions, but I can't make a clear distinction. Because both EASA and ICAO represent similar things. Does what is written as Jeppesen Standard AOM mean State minimums? I would appreciate it if you could explain all of them in a simpler and clearer way.

[image]
[image]
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Yes, EASA and ICAO are "similar", but they are also separate organizations with their own publications and standards.  Just like the FAA also has their own regulations that may be similar, yet different.

Each organization may have different methods or rules for determining approach minimums, and the definitions quoted in your question appear to be simply describing the source of the information that Jeppesen is publishing.